# http status code error 400: SOAP client in angular 4 with ngx-soap

Tags: angular, web-services, soap, angular-cli, http-status-code-400

I am trying to use a SOAP server in angular 4 with the ngx-soap package.

However, I am getting a Cross-Origin Request error (no access on the server side but there is no problem and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is good) and the http status code is 400.

I do not really know why i got this error. Please help me.

So this is my code (from ngx-soap package).

He created the SOAP client, calls the SOAP server (http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso) and uses a post request to recover the country name from the CountryName operation.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  jsonResponse: any;
  xmlResponse: string;
  message: string;
  loading: boolean;
  sCountryISOCode: string;
  private client: Client;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private soap: SOAPService
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/assets/tt.wsdl',
      {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      if (response) {
        this.client = this.soap.createClient(response);
      }
    });
  }

  soapCall() {
    this.clear();
    this.loading = true;
    const body = {
      sCountryISOCode: this.sCountryISOCode
    };
    this.client.operation('CountryName', body)
      .then(operation => {
        console.log(operation);
        if (operation.error) {
          console.log('Operation error', operation.error);
          return;
        }
        console.log(operation.url);
        console.log(operation.xml);
        console.log(operation.headers);
        this.http.post(operation.url, operation.xml,
          { headers: operation.headers, responseType: 'text', withCredentials: true }).subscribe(
          response => {
            console.log('GG');
            this.xmlResponse = response;
            this.jsonResponse = this.client.parseResponseBody(response);
            try {
              this.message = this.jsonResponse.Body.AddResponse.AddResult;
            } catch (error) { }
            this.loading = false;
          },
          err => {
            console.log('Error calling ws', err);
            this.loading = false;
            console.log();
          }
        );
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
  }
  clear() {
    this.message = undefined;
    this.jsonResponse = undefined;
    this.xmlResponse = undefined;
  }
}
export interface Output {
  AddResult?: string;
}
```